# Is my reduced row echelon form incorrect?

Tags: matrices

I need to find the reduced row echelon form of this matrix

-8   6   -2;
 6  -7    4;
-2   5   -3;
I performed the following row operations:

- r1+r2= -2   -2    2
- r2+2(r3)= 2   1   -2
- (-1/2)r1= 1   1   -1
- r2+r3=  0   5   -5
- r3+r2=0   5   -5
- r3-r2= 0   0   0
- (1/5)r2=  0   1    -1
- r1-r2= 1   0   0

So my RREF is:
1 0 0;
0 1 -1;
0 0 0;

I checked my answer and math.odu.edu gave this matrix as the answer:

1 0 -1/2;
0 1 -1;
0 0 0;

I know that for any matrix, the RREF is unique, so why is my answer different? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This site is for the computing software *Mathematica*. Perhaps you meant to ask this in [math.se]? (However, they probably frown on "Did I do this right?" kinds of questions. If you have a specific question about a mathematical concept/derivation, they'd be more likely to want to help.) You can however, use *Mathematica* to `RowReduce`, as shown in the answer below.

Comment: Are you asking a *mathematics* question?  (In that case, this is the wrong site.)  Or a question about the programming language *Mathematica*?

Comment: My bad, I wasn't aware of that! I'm sorry. I just wanted to know if my answer was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RowReduce[{{-8, 6, -2}, {6, -7, 4}, {-2, 5, -3}}]
```

(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} *)